# Tomcat Artifact seems to be empty

Tags: spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, deployment, artifact

It's about a backend server project in Java with Spring. The IDE is IntelliJ IDEA.The app worked just fine until after some shenanigans the artifact somehow disappeared.

I wanted to create a new one at Project Structure/Artifacts/+ and it is created and the Tomcat server launches from the IntelliJ config, but the launched app seems to bee 'empty', because I can't reach the rest api through the browser and there are no hibernate logs in the run window with database creating/populating.

The project has 2 modules (web and core) aside from the root module which is by default but that one contains no code. And the web module is dependent on the core (this is declared in the build.gradle of the web module through a compile project dependency) and it has the war plugin applied (this module is the only option when trying to generate a new artifact).

So what could I try to do or what other information can I provide to help you understand my problem?

Comment: Have you tried to reimport project from Gradle? It should recreate your artifact. Also please check what is included in your manually created artifact.

Comment: @y.bedrov I cleaned, recompiled and rebuilt the project countless times, through IntelliJ and through gradle too

Comment: I meant remove all IDE related data (.iml files and .idea folder) and reimport project from build.gradle.

Comment: @y.bedrov can't understand why or how, but it worked! thank you very much! (seriously tho, why all the recompiling/rebuilding/cleaning couldn't solve it?)

Comment: Recompile and rebuild actions don't change project configuration files that probably were corrupted